# Query with multiple date variables

Tags: php, mysql

I'm quite new to PHP and MySQL. I'm stuck with a problem, i will try to explain my problem.

```
 TODAY = 2013-01-13 18:37:00
 PRODUCT = P000001
```

TABEL : ASSEMBLY

```
  -----------------------------------------------------------------
  ∣ PRODUCT ∣ COMPONENT ∣      BEINFORCE      ∣     WILLEXPIRE      ∣
  -----------------------------------------------------------------
  ∣ P000001 ∣ C000001   ∣ 2013-01-01 18:37:00 ∣ 0000-00-00 00:00:00 ∣
  -----------------------------------------------------------------
  ∣ P000001 ∣ C000002   ∣ 2013-02-01 18:37:00 ∣ 0000-00-00 00:00:00 ∣
  -----------------------------------------------------------------
  ∣ P000001 ∣ C000003   ∣ 2013-01-01 18:37:00 ∣ 2013-01-10 18:37:00 ∣
  -----------------------------------------------------------------
```

Output must be:

```
  -----------------------------------------------------------------
  ∣ PRODUCT ∣ COMPONENT ∣      BEINFORCE      ∣     WILLEXPIRE      ∣
  -----------------------------------------------------------------
  ∣ P000001 ∣ C000001   ∣ 2013-01-01 18:37:00 ∣ 0000-00-00 00:00:00 ∣
  -----------------------------------------------------------------
```

Query from table ASSEMBLY must check PRODUCT, BEINFORCE and WILLEXPIRE and output table.

Comment: you mean u want get the first column ?? of COMPONENT

Comment: It's not clear what you are trying to do. Are you looking for an exact timestamp match against BEINFORCE? A timestamp from the same day? A timestamp within 24 hours of the specified one? Or a timestamp between BEINFORCE and WILLEXPIRE?

Comment: What is your business logic here?

Comment: Basically it’s a list of “COMPONENTS” which belong to “PRODUCT”  assembly “TODAY”. To list I need products where “BEINFORCE” is past and “WILLEXPIRE” is in future.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand you correctly, including the comment below your question, then you want those rows of `ASSEMBLY` which

1. have a `BEINFORCE` less than or equal to `TODAY`
2. have a `WILLEXPIRE` which is zero, which I take to denote a date in the future
3. match the `PRODUCT` you requested

You can achieve this using the following query, assuming user variables to represent your parameters. You could of course use prepared query placeholders as well.

```
SELECT *
FROM ASSEMBLY
WHERE BEINFORCE <= @TODAY
  AND WILLEXPIRE = '0000-00-00 00:00:00'
  AND PRODUCT = @PRODUCT
```

Comment: WILLEXPIRE needs to check twice, if "0000-00-00 00:00:00" and also if date inserted, if it in future then display it, if in past not to display it. "0000-00-00 00:00:00" means that WILLEXIRE is not inserted!

Comment: I think that problem is that i want to do - WILLEXPIRE = '0000-00-00 00:00:00' and also WILLEXPIRE > TODAY

Comment: @user1682101: `OR`, not `AND`, as you want to obtain the rows matching *either* of your two conditions. Enclose that in parentheses.

Comment: SELECT *
FROM `ASSEMBLY`
WHERE `BEINFORCE` <= "@TODAY"
AND (`WILLEXPIRE` >= "@TODAY"
OR `WILLEXPIRE` = "0000-00-00 00:00:00")
AND `PRODUCT` = "@PRODUCT"

Tried that, but still doesn't work?

Comment: Parentheses were solutions. I just had "@TODAY" fixed for testing. So, thank you, seems that everything works just fine!